# MYSQL: Update replace on 2million records

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have over 2 million phone numbers in one table and I need to remove all the spaces from the phone field.

I have INDEX the phone field and optimised the table but still when i run the following query it is so slow and takes forever - in fact I am still waiting and 30minutes have past

```
UPDATE ACTNSW SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '');
```

I need to know if there is away to speed up this process so that it does not take so long.

Database scheeme it is using is `InnoDB`
Server version: 5.5.31-1 (Debian)

Comment: Since this is a one-time operation, does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is basic sql query . you can't do much about it but you can do one thing don't run update
query for whole table . make multiple update queries something like ..

```
UPDATE ACTNSW SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '') where id < .2 milian
UPDATE ACTNSW SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '') where id < .4 milian and id > .2 milian
UPDATE ACTNSW SET phone = REPLACE(phone, ' ', '') where id > .5 milian and id > .4 milian
....
```

I think it will help you .

Comment: The point is if you break then it will take less memory at a time . so it will run properly .

Comment: I don't see why memory usage would be materially different.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility of doing the update offline, you could use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) to output the contents of the table. Next perform your replace operation on the file with sed/awk. Then drop your table on the server and restore it with the dumpfile.